# Error: The middleware loopback.favicon is not installed

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback,
I setup a new loopback application, and run `npm install` and after doing

```
node server/server.js
```

I am getting the below mentioned error, I tried googling it, but was of no use,,,

```
Error: The middleware loopback.favicon is not installed.
Run `npm install --save serve-favicon` to fix the problem.
    at /home/nishant/nishant/goibibo_ugc/node_modules/loopback/lib/express-middleware.js:18:11
    at Function.middlewares.favicon (/home/nishant/nishant/goibibo_ugc/node_modules/loopback/lib/express-middleware.js:52:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nishant/nishant/goibibo_ugc/server/server.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Nothing is mentioned about it on loopback documentation either,

Comment: this is bug in express 4.8.5 / in 4.8.4 all ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
npm uninstall -g strongloop
npm install -g strongloop
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

This should fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have not got a suitable fix for the above problem, but for temporary work,,

Have commented the line

```
// Set up the /favicon.ico
//app.use(loopback.favicon());
```

After which the server started, and working fine

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

- npm install --save serve-favicon

which is aleady indicated there in error response.

Also check https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/500